# Set timeout in simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Can i set timeout for `file_get_html()` in simple_html_dom?

I need that this call wait for 5 sec. to render all scripts in a page.

Or another way to do this in PHP, parsing html pages using css selectors?

Comment: you have to set timeout or you want delay the rendering?

Comment: `simple_html_dom` is an html parser. Is does not understand or execute javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that with `simple_html_dom()` or `file_get_contents()` or any other 'pure' PHP.

For this purpose you have to use technologies like PhantomJS. Load the page into PhantomJS, wait for JavaScript to finish executing, then use the HTML that has been generated.

[PHP PhantomJS](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs) should make that quite simple (see the "[Delay page render](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/4.0/usage/#delay-page-render)" example in the Documentation).